# Does Swift handle application start paths differently on different Macs? Frustrating inconsistencies

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa

In my program, I am calling other binaries and applications that are within the (application name)/Contents/Resources folder. On my Mac, I am doing so by first getting the starting directory of my program, then asking it to open as a task. I noticed this works great on my Mac, but when I test it on a friend's Mac, the "starting path" returns just "/" - which is frustrating. I have tried SEVERAL methods, including:

```
let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
let path = fileManager.currentDirectoryPath
print(path)
```

as well as

```
bundle.main.executablepath
```

and

```
bundle.main.bundlepath
```

and last but not least, I even tried using Process / Pipe to ask the os:

```
    task.launchPath = "/bin/sh"
    task.arguments = ["-c", "pwd"]
```

The issue here is that on my machine, these ALL produce either the directory containing the app (which is fine,) or a directory inside the app (which is also fine,)

but on the other Macs, it's either giving me "/", OR even weirder, **it's giving me something like "/var/private/folders" etc**, and that strange directory doesn't contain the contents of my app. What's going on here?

This is XCode 11.1, latest Swift/Storyboards for macOS. Currently running latest Catalina.

Comment: Sandboxed apps use their containers, but standard APIs such as Bundle's [path(forResource:ofType:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/bundle/1410989-path) should give you the file item.

Comment: [`currentDirectoryPath`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/1410766-currentdirectorypath) and `pwd` both give the process's current working directory, which is not generally related to the location of the app. The working directory is inherited from whatever process started the program, so it'll depend on how your app was launched. It is not relevant for finding your app bundle.

Comment: Don't use paths, use URLs. Do the `url(forResource:` methods of `Bundle` work?